# skip Helm uninstall interactive request

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

i want to automate a bit helm install/uninstall but during helm uninstall command it will become user interactiv asking:

Do you want to continue to delete suite-helm? (yY|nN):

Is any flag or way to skip this part?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i miss to add the command used by me: helm uninstall suite-helm -n suite-helm

Comment: What version of Helm?  Do you have a local fork, or any particular plugins?  I run `helm uninstall` pretty routinely and I don't think I get asked this; I'd expect [`helm uninstall`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_uninstall/) to have a `-f` or `-y` option to avoid it exactly for this scripting use case and don't see one.

Answer (score 1):

finaly i found a way using expect and here it is:
**expect -c ' spawn ./helm_remove.sh; expect (yY|nN); send "y\n"; interact'**

into sh file i will have **helm uninstall suite-helm -n suite-helm** and some other commands to remove pvs deployment...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to wrap in a shell script or function.

Something like (just spitballing here, not even syntax checking)

```
helm-delete() {

helm status $1

echo "Do you want to continue to delete suite-helm? (yY|nN):"
read -rs -k 1 ans

    case "${ans}" in
    y|Y|$'\n')
        printf "Yes\n"

          helm delete %1
        ;;

    *)  # This is the default
        printf "No\n"
            return 0

    esac
}
```

Comment: i tried even like this and also using expect but it's not working becaause it's not a normal tty is like inside of helm comand line. So any other ideea?

Comment: this is meant to be outside of the helm cli not inside for inside of the command your going to need to submit a patch to https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/cmd/helm/plugin_uninstall.go